# React-native backend for i18next

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next

How i can load translations json files in RN? In browser i [can use](https://www.i18next.com/plugins-and-utils.html#backends) fetch and XHR, but in application it must be some kind of file system acces with copy translations to ./android/app/src/main/assets/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We load the using the xhr-backend. Not yet had the need to cache those on asyncStorage but doing so would be rather easy - copy of the https://github.com/i18next/i18next-localStorage-cache using asyncStorage

Or add them using i18next.addResourceBundle: https://www.i18next.com/api.html#addresourcebundle

Or use a webpack bundler: https://github.com/atroo/i18next-resource-store-loader

But a loader from filesystem of phone would be great too, not yet know if someone built that.

Comment: thanks, i will try addResourceBundle. 
also in RN there is no webpack